# How can I parse a lua file in R

Tags: r, lua

Hello I would like to read a lua file in R. Is there a package that would enable me to read lua into R and write R lists and simple data structures into a lua file ?
The usecase would be to read bunch a lua file, "merge" them in R, and write another lua file with the merged result

Comment: Possibly this might help: http://scilua.org/rclient.html. It allows to run R from within Lua.

Comment: @Sven thank you but no, I want to drive from R and just be able to programatically read/write lua files